# Adjust network data that edges go both ways

Tags: r, tidyr, data-wrangling

I have data.frame containing a list of people and who they are neighbours with. However, the data suggest that Josh a neighbour of himself, Emma, and Nick, but Emma is not a neighbour of Josh.

```
x <- read.table(text = "
Name ID Neighbour_ID
Josh 1 1,2,3
Emma 2 4
Nick 3 1
Mark 4 5
Claire 5 
", sep = " ", header = TRUE)

x

 Name     ID      Neighbour_ID
1   Josh  1      1,2,3
2   Emma  2          4
3   Nick  3          1
4   Mark  4          5
5 Claire  5
```

This of course needs to be fixed and I am looking for a way to do that. The outcome should look like this

```
 Name     ID      Neighbour_ID
1   Josh  1        2,3
2   Emma  2        1,4
3   Nick  3          1
4   Mark  4        2,5
5 Claire  5          4
```

Add: If you find a better suited title for this question please feel free to edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x %>%
  separate_rows(Neighbour_ID, convert = TRUE) %>% 
  select(-Name) %>%
  rbind(setNames(rev(.), names(.))) %>%
  filter(ID != Neighbour_ID) %>%
  distinct()%>%
  left_join(select(x, -Neighbour_ID), c(ID = 'ID')) %>%
  summarise(Neighbour_ID = toString(sort(Neighbour_ID)), .by = c(Name, ID))

  # A tibble: 5 × 3
  Name      ID Neighbour_ID
  <chr>  <int> <chr>       
1 Josh       1 2, 3        
2 Emma       2 1, 4        
3 Nick       3 1           
4 Mark       4 2, 5        
5 Claire     5 4
```

Comment: If I use your code I receive ```A tibble: 16 × 2
   Neighbour_ID           .by   
   <chr>                  <chr> 
 1 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5 Josh  
 2 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5 Josh  
 3 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5 Emma  
 4 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5 Nick  
 5 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5 Mark  
 6 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5 Emma  
 7 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5 Mark  
 8 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5 Claire
 9 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5 1     
10 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5 1     
11 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5 2     
12 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5 3     
...    ```

Comment: @KC15 you are using an older version of `dplyr` ie it does not take into consideration the `.by`. In the older version, before the final summarize statement, use `group_by(Name, ID)` and then in the summary statement, dont use `.by`

Answer (score 2):

Using *igraph* package, convert it to graph object:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(igraph)

g <- separate_rows(x, Neighbour_ID, convert = TRUE) %>% 
  select(from = ID, to = Neighbour_ID) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(to) & from != to) %>% 
  graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE)

g
# IGRAPH 1eeedee UN-- 5 5 -- 
# + attr: name (v/c)
# + edges from 1eeedee (vertex names):
#   [1] 1--2 1--3 2--4 1--3 4--5
plot(g)
```

[image]

I'd stop here, as we have our data in *graph* format. But if you need your output as *data.frame* then get the *edgelists* and merge back to original data.

```
gEdge <- get.edgelist(g)
left_join(x %>% select(Name, ID),
          data.frame(unique(rbind(gEdge[, 1:2], gEdge[, 2:1]))) %>%
            mutate(X1 = as.integer(X1), X2 = as.integer(X2)) %>% 
            summarise(Neighbour_ID = paste(sort(X2), collapse = ","), .by = X1),
          by = c("ID" = "X1"))

#     Name ID Neighbour_ID
# 1   Josh  1          2,3
# 2   Emma  2          1,4
# 3   Nick  3            1
# 4   Mark  4          2,5
# 5 Claire  5            4
```

Comment: Thanks, however according to the data Josh is still Josh's neighbour... which he of course is not.

Comment: Error in `left_join()`:
! Join columns must be present in data.
✖ Problem with `X is an error I get when replicating your solution

Comment: @KC15 then maybe change your expected output?

Comment: @KC15 edited, remove when `from`  and `to` are the same.